# Insert value in a column conditionally in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, sql-max

I have a table Persons with columns `PersonId`, `FirstName`, `DeptId` and `City`. The `PersonId` is a Primary Key.

By default on first insert, I want the first entry for the `DeptId` to have a value of `3000`. And the subsequent entries should always increment on the last value of `DeptId`.

Can someone please help me with that in MySQL ?

```
1 John 3000 Port Mathurin
2 James 3001 Port Desny

insert into `Persons` (`PersonID`, `FirstName`, `DeptId`, `City`) VALUES (1, 'Job', select `DeptId` from `Persons` +1, 'Port Mathurin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `INSERT ... VALUES` use `INSERT ... SELECT` to select the max `DeptId` from `Persons`:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, FirstName, DeptId, City) 
SELECT 1, 'Job', COALESCE(MAX(DeptId), 2999) + 1, 'Port Mathurin' 
FROM Persons;
```

`COALESCE()` will return `2999` when the table is empty and with `+1` the result will be `3000` for the `DeptId` of the 1st row of the table.